CMFCEditBrowseCtrl icon does not render as disabled when using EnableWindow(false). How to fix?
I am using the CMFCEditBrowseCtrl and display my own icon.
There are times when I want to disable the control (ie. m_control.EnableWindow(false);. But it does not behave as I expect:

It is disabled, but the icon does not grey out. And this looks weird I think. What is the right way to address this?
This is how I assign the image to use (during OnInitDialog):
m_control.SetBrowseButtonImage(IDB_PNG_IMAGE);


Does EnableBrowseButton() work or does it hide the button altogether? If it is the latter you probably have to supply a "disabled" button image manually. DrawState() can be used to derive the appropriate image, though I expect the quality to be somewhat poor.

@IInspectable According to the documentation it states it will not show it: "Displays or does not display the browse button on the current edit browse control.". I did notice OnDrawBrowseButton and wondered if it could be used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class?view=msvc-170#ondrawbrowsebutton

You can use it, but you need to overwrite the function and implement your own drawing of the button. CMFCVisualManager::GetInstance()->OnDrawBrowseButton doesn't have a case or state for an enabled or disabled button.

@xMRi I am surprised that the control does not cater for this basic functionality of disabling the control.

Yes it is strange for me too, that the enum AFX_BUTTON_STATE
{
ButtonsIsRegular,
ButtonsIsPressed,
ButtonsIsHighlighted,
}; doesn't have a case for disabled! Incomplete design...

@xMRi those CMFC* classes are terribly botched.
